# Is it possible to add settings to "allow-plugins" in config section in composer.json through the CLI?

Tags: php, composer-php, command-line-interface

Since composer 2.2 the setting `allow-plugins` will be compulsory I’ve tried to push this setting through the `composer config` command in the CLI but with no luck.

I’ve tried a few commands like:

- `composer config --json '{"allow-plugins.composer/installers":true, "allow-plugins.dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true, "allow-plugins.roots/wordpress-core-installer": true }'`
- `composer config config.allow-plugins '{"composer/installers":true, "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true, "wordpress-core-installer": true}'`
- `composer config --append "allow-plugins" "composer/installers":true, "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true, "wordpress-core-installer": true`
- `composer config --json "allow-plugins" '{"composer/installers":true, "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true, "roots/wordpress-core-installer": true }'`

All I get is error messages like ".. is not defined" or that it is an invalid value.

What I have is this:

```
​ "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist"
},​​​​​​
```

And, I need to add the settings like this:

```
​​​"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "roots/wordpress-core-installer": true
     }
},​​​​​
```

Is this possible through the CLI?

Comment: Read current composer.json, edit it with jq lib, save as new file and pass it with `--file="my-new-composer.json"`?

Comment: @Justinas That seems serious overkill. The command line interface allows to add values directly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to pass set them one by one.

```
composer config allow-plugins.composer/installers true
composer config allow-plugins.dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer  true
composer config allow-plugins.roots/wordpress-core-installer true
```

Edit per conversation in comments:

OP was looking to also achieve not being prompted during the command. To do this, we must pass the `--no-interaction` (or `-n`) option. This can be useful when performing automation tasks.

Full Example of OP's Plugins:

```
composer config --no-interaction allow-plugins.composer/installerstrue
composer config --no-interaction allow-plugins.dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer true
composer config --no-interaction allow-plugins.roots/wordpress-core-installer true
```

Comment: Ohhh! So yes, that works so thanks for that! But here's the problem - since I need to push the same command to 60+ sites at the same time I would like to not have to push "y" to confirm the command. Is there a way around it perhaps? Otherwise I have to manually push "y" for these three commands for all the sites, but it would be nice to not have to.

Comment: What do you mean "pushing y"? I do not need to confirm anything when using the `config` command. Have you tried the command and got a confirmation prompt?

Comment: Hmmm, okay. This is what I got from the command: 


```composer config allow-plugins.composer/installers true```

```composer/installers contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "composer/installers" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] y```

Comment: That's because your **global** composer also has plugins. You should get the prompt only once (which will change your global composer `config.allow-plugins`setting.

Comment: Yeah, absolutley. But it still causes me to have to confirm the plugins for all the 60+ sites - even though just once, so that´s why I would like to set the allowed plugins and not have to confirm them, all in just one command. That way I could use that command for all the sites.

Comment: Just run `composer global config allow-plugins.composer/installers true`  before the rest. But if your global composer require any other plugin, you'll need to allow those too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :) when I add -n after the command then I don't need to confirm and the plugin was added to the allow-plugin to the config section exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to composer.json

```
"config": {
        "allow-plugins": true
   }
```